# DOM reload after ajax form injection

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, jquery-selectors

Ive tried similar questions to no avail.

My question is simply how to reload the DOM after an ajax request has been made?
Its not a question regarding event delegation, rather one concerning jquery selectors.

**sample:**

```
editUser : function(){
            var editItem = $("a.edit");


            editItem.on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

               //click the users tab & the edit tab
                var usersjq = $("li#users-jq");
                usersjq.find("a").eq(0).click();
                $("ul.tabs").find("a").eq(2).click();


                var uid = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
                $(".three #users-edit").empty();

                $(".three #users-edit").load(BASE_PATH + 'users/admin/users/edit/' + uid, function(){
                   //loads a form with id of #form-users-edit

                }, 'html');



            });
        },
formEditUsers : function(){

            //#form-users-edit is not selectable

            //all of these just return jQuery ( ) 
            console.log($(".three #users-edit").find("#form-users-edit"));
            console.log($(document.forms));
            console.log($("form#form-users-edit"));

        }
```

Regards.

Comment: Do you want to reload the page or just want to execute the document.ready function ?

Comment: "reload the DOM" - needs to be defined.

Comment: the latter, $(document).trigger("ready"); wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing *formEditUsers(*) into the ajax success callback seems to work fine.